# how can i set affinity in my bat file for loop

Tags: batch-file, affinity

I have a bat file that calls a program to cycle through a list of files to process. I like to run multiple instance at the same time, and some times they cause each other to crash. I would like to be able to have 8 or more instances running at the same time with no issues. To do this I need each instance to run on it's own core.
My question is, where in my bat file do i specify the affinity to be used?
Here is an example of the bat file as it is now

```
 @ECHO OFF

programX.exe ac %1

echo %date% %time% Completed programX on %1 >> programX_log.txt
```

Comment: Are you looking for the `start` command? type `start /?` into a new command prompt window and check out the `/AFFINITY` option...

Comment: Would that work in an instance where programX.exe sat in a processing folder it was working in? Basically there would be dozens of instances of programX in different processing folders that I would want to be running at the same time.

Comment: A script copies template processing folders to a new working directory base on a few variables. So in E:\DIR_A\ there would be 8 working folders, \working1,  \working2, and so on. Each housing programX which would be running. I'm trying to tell the program in \working2 that it gets core 1 and 2 only, \working3 gets 3 and 4, and so on.

Comment: figured it out using python